# Shortcut Keys in VMware Workstation Guest is also captured by Host

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, vmware

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.10 x64 as host. This machine is used as a host for a VMWare Workstation 14 Pro (Version:14.1.0 build-7370693) (guests: macos 10.13 high sierra and Windows 10 x64).

All nice and good until I realized that when I press the win key on guest or any other shortcut key (full-screen or exclusive mode) it opens the Ubuntu dash menu but not the windows start menu. It also capturing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> and other such keys that also have key-bindings in host and act according to host but not the guest. Basically, any combination of <kbd>super</kbd> + anything only work on host  which is really annoying.

I need to mention that I don't want a solution like, replace the super key in guest or permanently disable <kbd>super</kbd> key on host, or just get rid of VMware and use Virtual-box. I just need it to work as expected.

Any help will be highly appreciated!